# Nodejs security best practice regarding string values

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, security

I need to get the IP address using nodejs/express.
Below is the statement I use for this.

```
const ipAddress = String(req.ip || "unknown");
```

Since req.ip originates from an HTTP header, a malicious user could change it.
Is this then the best way to get the user's IP address?

Comment: Too many bugs were introduced here so I posted a solution below.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose how "secure" it is depends on what you are trying to secure against.

Generally an IP should be considered transient - users on mobile can enter or exit wifi or different cell towers, and their IP can change. IPs can also be spoofed.

If you are using Express, [`req.ip` does NOT normally come from a header but from the connection itself](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.ip). The exception is if you are using a reverse proxy -- are you? In which case we'll need more details about the proxy being used and your proxy setup. Proxies should be configured to always overwrite the `X-Forwarded-For` sent by the client, such that the header can always be trusted.

Comment: I was concerned about a user being able to mutate the value.

Comment: The last paragraph addresses this. Since the IP does not come from a header, how would a user mutate the value, aside from spoofing?

Comment: Agreed, but you asked what I was concerned about and I was just saying that I didn't realize req.ip came from the connection and not the header. I also use this syntax in other situations where headers are used though. So it was nice to resolve this nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I changed the above to:

```
let ipAddress = "";
if (req.ip === undefined) ipAddress = "unknown";
else ipAddress = String(req.ip);
```

Comment: It's not clear how this is any better than what you originally had.

Comment: If a user input "0" it would evaluate to false, and provide a return value of "unknown". This would be a correct return in this case as "0" is invalid as an IP address, but it's confusing. The new way is easier to read.

Comment: In this case, yes. Thank you for clarifying.